# How can I add a border to an image that has padding?

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my webpage that I added padding to so it wouldn't be in the corner. I also wanted to give it a border but the border is showing up around the empty space instead of just the image... What am I doing wrong?

The image also has a float attribute.

```
img {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fdb924;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the image a `margin` instead of `padding`:

```css
img {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fdb924;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the padding to margin. `padding` is the space between the border and the image, while `margin` is the space between the border and everything outside of it: https://jsfiddle.net/632t5g8x/